# Node Facebook Passport only returns certain fields regardless of sent scope

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm currently trying to implement Facebooks OAUTH by using `Koa-Passport` and `Koajs 2`

Everythings working fine and I can login and what not, but regardless of what I send in the scope I only ever get:

```
{ passport:
   { user:
      { id: '1015401',
        username: undefined,
        displayName: 'John Doe',
        name: [Object],
        gender: undefined,
        profileUrl: undefined,
        provider: 'facebook',
        _raw: '{"name":"John Doe","id":"1015401"}',
        _json: [Object] } } }
```

I've tried adding

`scope: ['email', 'public_profile']` which seems to work on Facebooks end because I can see the information my app is requesting which all the stuff is there.

But when I hit ok and I get redirected back to my app, again I'm missing things like a `profile_pic` field and `email` field. Any information on how to get these fields back would be great thanks. I would open an issue on the github page but there are issues dating back to 2013 it doesn't seem to be maintained very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and **solved it** by doing the following:

in `passport.js` add the line with `profileFields`:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: clientID,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        callbackURL: callbackURL,
        profileFields: ['id', 'name', 'emails']
      },
```

`'emails'` will return an array of emails, so get the first value:

```
newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
```

Let us know if that worked for you, maybe that will be helpful for others as well.